# How Do I Redirect a Wordpress Website?

Tags: wp-redirect, subdomains, domain

I have a staging Wordpress site with HostGator at `http://subdomain.domain1.com` (This is not the actual domain, however it is a subdomain of an existing domain.)

I purchased a new domain from Namecheap and let's call that `http://domain2.com`.

What I want to happen is if someone enters subdomain.domain1.com I want them taken to domain2.com. On domain2.com I want the site that is currently at domain1.com to be displayed.

Is this possible? Sorry, I know this is probable a simple question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WordPress site at the location of the subdomain, you can simply create a redirect with this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/.